# I'm developing a mern application and I'm stuck with the error TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined on chrome console

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

I'm developing a `mern` application and I'm stuck with the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined on chrome console

[image]

The database is connected and is working fine. Front-end is also connected to backend, and works fine.

Comment: props.mernapp object might not has username property.. put a console and check what you getting in props.mernapp object.. 
props.mernapp ? props.mernapp.username : null  this condition will help you from app crash.

Comment: please post your code, it is difficult without code.
1) Just check whether mernapp is getting data.
2) Check if you are passing data to Log component from parent component
3) Check if mernapp has username key